# How do I caption an Array?

Tags: tables, captions, arrays

So far, this is what I got.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{appendix}
\frenchspacing
 $\begin{array}{  l  l  l  l  l  }
 & Stage & ln\_labor & ln\_hours & p(emp) \\ \hline\hline
\text{Currently living in urban areas}  & 1st & 0.21482 & 0.13242 & 0.19161 \\ 
 & 2nd & -0.09168 & -0.06626 & -0.16811 \\ \hline
\text{Lived in a state capital when aged 15} & 1st & 0.47462 & 0.63929^{*} & 0.95309^{**} \\ 
 & 2nd & 0.04447 & 0.11124 & -0.08064 \\ \hline
\text{Lived in urban area when aged 15} & 1st & 0.65694^{**} & 0.57415^{**} & 0.60316^{*} \\ 
 & 2nd & 0.24461^{**} & 0.15895 & -0.08445 \\ \hline
\text{Currently living in urban areas}  & 1st & 0.01835 & 0.02033 & 0.01678 \\ 
 & 2nd & -1.198 & -0.54056 & -1.7587 \\ \hline
\text{Lived in a state capital when aged 15} & 1st & 0.04432 & 0.0328 & 0.0331 \\ 
 & 2nd & 1.822 & 2.263 & 0.01657 \\ \hline
\text{Lived in urban area when aged 15} & 1st & 0.09357^{**} & 0.08919^{**} & 0.09271^{***} \\ 
 & 2nd & 1.775^{**} & 1.1184 & -0.26679 \\ 
\caption{$*$ for significant at $10\%$, $**$ for significance at $5\%$ and $***$ for significance at $1\%$}

\end{array}
$
```

And I get this error message:

```
Package caption Error: \caption outside float.

See the caption package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \caption
             {$*$ for significant at $10\%$, $**$ for significance at $5\%$ ...
```

So, what do I do?

Comment: Off-topic: The *caption* of a table should normally consist of a brief statement regarding the contents of the table. Using the `\caption` command to provide auxilliary information -- e.g., to explain what 1, 2, and 3 stars mean -- is rather unusual. For your table, something like `\caption{Regression results}` (or whatever is most appropriate) would seem to be called for. And, to make sure that people will notice the caption easily, place it *above* the tabular material. The string "`$*$ for significant ... $1\%$`" can still be placed below the tabular material.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example, environment `table` can be added:

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{...}
  $\begin{array}{...}
    ...
  \end{array}$
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, `caption` is normally inserted inside a float environment like `table` and `figure`. Here, `table` seems more correct. Second, you used `array` instead of `tabular` though the content is mainly text, switch to `tabular`. Third, to better align numbers use the `dcolumn` package to align numbers around the decimal point. Finally, using `booktabs` can greatly improve readability with adding small spaces between different rows, `\addlinespace`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn} 
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\caption{$^*$for significant at 10\%, $^{**}$for significance at 5\% and $^{***}$for significance at $1\%$}\par\medskip
\begin{tabular}{ @{} l l *3{D{.}{.}{6}} }
\toprule
 & Stage & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ln\_labor} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ln\_hours} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p(emp)} \\ \midrule
Currently living in urban areas  & 1\textsuperscript{st} & 0.21482 & 0.13242 & 0.19161 \\ 
 & 2\textsuperscript{nd} & -0.09168 & -0.06626 & -0.16811 \\ \addlinespace
Lived in a state capital when aged 15 & 1\textsuperscript{st} & 0.47462 & 0.63929^{*} & 0.95309^{**} \\ 
 & 2\textsuperscript{nd} & 0.04447 & 0.11124 & -0.08064 \\ \addlinespace
Lived in urban area when aged 15 & 1\textsuperscript{st} & 0.65694^{**} & 0.57415^{**} & 0.60316^{*} \\ 
 & 2\textsuperscript{nd} & 0.24461^{**} & 0.15895 & -0.08445 \\ \addlinespace
Currently living in urban areas  & 1\textsuperscript{st} & 0.01835 & 0.02033 & 0.01678 \\ 
 & 2\textsuperscript{nd} & -1.198 & -0.54056 & -1.7587 \\ \addlinespace
Lived in a state capital when aged 15 & 1\textsuperscript{st} & 0.04432 & 0.0328 & 0.0331 \\ 
 & 2\textsuperscript{nd} & 1.822 & 2.263 & 0.01657 \\ \addlinespace
Lived in urban area when aged 15 & 1\textsuperscript{st} & 0.09357^{**} & 0.08919^{**} & 0.09271^{***} \\ 
 & 2\textsuperscript{nd} & 1.775^{**} & 1.1184 & -0.26679 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]